# Setting One row in a Table to 1 and Others to 0 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a table Which has a column named ActiveStatus(bit Data type). I have several rows for One Id. When I Change the Active status to 1 all the other remaining rows with same Ids  should be Changed to 0

Can any One Help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any efforts with examples?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can do something like:

```
update t
    set ActiveStatus = (case when <however you identify your special row>
                             then 1 else 0
                        end)
    where id = @id;
```